# Wordpress pagination Same code but acts differently

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

my pagination was not working on one of the page
so I have the same query and code on two different template 
for the working one but the code still acts differently.

It is pulling different additional category and the pagination 
goes no where but the first page for one of the template..

can someone take a look at what is going on?

```
<?php $blog = new WP_Query('cat=29'); ?>
        <?php while($blog->have_posts()): $blog->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $more = 0; ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => '5',
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
            );
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if($attachments || has_post_thumbnail() || get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pyre_video', true)):
            ?>
            <div class="flexslider blog-medium-image floated-post-slideshow">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pyre_video', true)): ?>
                    <li class="video">
                        <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pyre_video', true); ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                    <?php $full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); ?>
                    <?php $attachment_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata(get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-medium'); ?>
                                <?php if(count($attachments) == 0): ?>
                                <div class="image-extras">
                                    <div class="image-extras-content">
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/link-ico.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php foreach($attachments as $attachment): ?>
                    <?php $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'blog-medium'); ?>
                    <?php $full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full'); ?>
                    <?php $attachment_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment->ID); ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $attachment_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $attachment->post_title; ?>" />
                                <?php if(count($attachments) == 0): ?>
                                <div class="image-extras">
                                    <div class="image-extras-content">
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/link-ico.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_content(''); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="meta-info">
                <div class="alignleft">
                    By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?><span class="sep">|</span><?php the_category(', '); ?><span class="sep">|</span><?php comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="alignright">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more"><?php _e('Read More', 'Avada'); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php kriesi_pagination($blog->max_num_pages, $range = 2); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $blog = new WP_Query( array ( 'posts_per_page' => '5','category__in' => array( 27, 28, 30 ),'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ), )); ?>
```

thanks for helping me out, but i found an article and added this query in which fixed
my issue about the pagination.